# Cannot set php session variable to another php page

Tags: php, mysql, database

I cannot set a session variable on one page to another my code is below.

first page

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');

///mysql connections
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sthpre )){
// Print out the contents of each row into a table

$rows[] = $row; 
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
print json_encode($row);

}//still i get null on the other page $_SESSION['id'] = 22;
```

second page

```
session_start();
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
$row['id']=$_SESSION['id'];
print json_encode($row);
```

Comment: dont print any output before the HEADER

Comment: are you getting Headers already sent error?

Comment: check if your file is UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: i have changed , still null, ican see id on the first page but null on the second one, yes utf-8 without bom. no headers error, json returns id:null

Comment: varavle $row[id] must be ju s t $row=$_SESSION['id']

Comment: Try without the headers

Comment: without header cant handle json,

Comment: check `echo session_id();` on both pages.

Comment: after getting session variable should i header location to go to another page?

Comment: Did you check the session_id() on both? My guess is that the directory where sessions are trying to write on your server isn't writable by the apache user.

Comment: first page i can pass the variable to session['id'], but cant in the second, second page shows null

Comment: I know that. I'm asking you to `echo session_id();` on both pages to help debug your problem. Let us know what the session_id is on both pages.

Comment: different from eachother @Pitchinnate

Comment: Ok that is your problem then.

Comment: Also just to make sure since we don't know your experience level, you are checking in the same browser correct? Not one page in Chrome and the other in Firefox, right?

Comment: i am pinging from mobile application login and then it have to pull sessions from previous login page, am i wrong? @Pitchinnate

Comment: So both calls are from the same mobile app? If so I'm not sure if the mobile app would maintain a consistent session_id or not.

Comment: yes same time same login same redirect same phone same app in 3 seconds

Comment: i think mobile app has to be have its own cookies

Comment: Yeah i'm sure it does look at my updated answer below see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

> > session_start();
> >
> > session_regenerate();
> >
> > header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
> >
> > $row['id']=$_SESSION['id'];
> >     print json_encode($row);

Answer (score 0):

Based off of the knowledge that you have a different session id in each page my guess is that the directory that php is trying to use to store sessions is not writable by the apache user. If you create a page and put:

```
session_save_path();
```

It will tell you where php is trying to write the session information on the server. Make sure the directory it displays to you is writable by the apache user (most likely www-data). Or change it to a different directory that is writable. You can do it in your code like this:

```
session_save_path('/tmp');
```

Or you can change it in your php.ini file.

If that isn't the issue and it is because your app isn't maintaining a consistent session id you can force a session_id.

```
session_start();
session_id('5468313'); //any random id
```

Just do this in both files however you will need to generate a different session id for each person who logs in otherwise everyone will be sharing the same session.